# Capture Image of Entire Panel Control In Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, panel

I have added some richtextboxes and some picture boxes in a panel control with scrolling option enabled. I want to capture image of Panel control along with all its child controls. I tried various solutions available on net but still not able to find perfect solution to do my job. The best one available (which dose not capture what is off the scroll bars) is given below. Please help me to do this.

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
    Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        gr.CopyFromScreen(Panel1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, Panel1.Size)
    End Using
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a screen shot out side of the program itself? As in the whole desktop? Is that your problem, or am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you use Control.DrawToBitmap instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: When i use Control.DrawToBitmap it will give you image of control but it has a problem. If you are using richtextbox control in a panel and user changed the text of richtextbox it will not appear in the image taken useng Control.DrawToBitmap.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
G.CopyFromScreen(Panel1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
End Using
Return tmpImg
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TakeScreenShot(Panel1).Save("D:\Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```